# PHP check if data and time more than date and time for this moment

Tags: php, time

Hey i want to check if time and date more than time right now
ex

```
if ( date("Y:m:j:H:i:s") >  strtotime("2017:09:27:14:02:05") ) {
 // TODO
}
```

Comment: So you're converting on timestamp to a formatted string (`date("Y:m:j:H:i:s")`) and a formatted string to a timestamp (`strtotime("2017:09:27:14:02:05")`) and then comparing?!? Use timestamps for both! Hint: [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

Comment: Throw both times into a `DateTime` class and then do a `if >` on them

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
$date = "2017:09:27:14:02:05";

if ( date("Y:m:j:H:i:s") >  date('Y:m:j:H:i:s', strtotime($date)) ) {

}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Excessive use of functions, surely

Comment: Thank but not working , what i want is make a expiry date for something if expire will remove it , sorry for my bad English ..